# Amazon EC2: Switching between VM types

Tags: amazon-ec2

How long does it take to switch from one VM type to another ? (small to large for example)

If you are using windows VM, will you need to reconfigure your server?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot switch instance types while they are running, so your update should be shutting down the small instance and booting up the large one. If you have custom software installed, you have to reinstall it just like with a completely fresh machine.

Answer (score 0):

Further to j0nes' answer, if you create a custom AMI from your initial instance after you've installed all your custom software, you can use it to launch a new instance of a different instance type without having to reconfigure anything.  See the [EC2 User Guide](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/) for details.

Comment: Only problem with this is that a m1.small instance is a 32-bit platform and a m1.large or bigger is a 64-bit platform.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot upgrading a running instance from one VM type to another.

You *can* stop a running instance (even an EBS-based image, I think) and start it up under another VM type.

I use this when doing development: I'm slow so I use the slow 'small' instance when working on cloud infrastructure stuff, but when it runs 'for real' as part of our automated systems, it runs as a High-CPU machine type.